# I recently installed a new library for python, but the classes aren't being recognized

Tags: python-3.x, google-colaboratory

I've been using Google CoLab for a project and recently imported the library [pycotools3](https://readthedocs.org/projects/pycotools3/downloads/pdf/develop/) from a public receptacle to help move some data I have over to COPASI. However, though pycotools3 is recognized by CoLab, none of its classes are.

For instance, when I try any of the following:

```
from pycotools3 import model
from pycotools3.model import model
from pycotools3 import Model
from pycotools3.model import Model
```

I receive the error message: "cannot import name 'model'" or "No module named 'pycotools.model'".
The same thing happens with any of the other classes (tasks and viz).

Any ideas on why this is happening or how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured out the problem, so I wanted to answer this in case anyone else has a similar issue. Numpy and scipy, which pycotools3 interacts with, were not up to date. I had updated them for this project, but never restarted my runtime. After restarting my runtime on CoLab, 'model' was recognized.